# Looping through Cells in a Range: Cell.Value method

Tags: excel, vba

```
For Each cell In stats
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
    Call WriteStatistic(cell)
End If
```

I have the above code to loop through cells in a range. Stats.address returns "$AT$45:$AT$76" and the values in these cells are 0 or another integer in General format. The problem that I am having is the cell.Value method. When I put it to a MsgBox, it returns blank. When I specify the cell using

```
Range("AT45").Value
```

it returns the number in the cell. Also interesting: when I call cell.address within that loop, it successfully returns the cell address. Is there something I am forgetting? I have declared cell as a Range object and it still does this.

Comment: When you set stats do you assign the correct parent sheet?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I am only working with one sheet and assigning everything to that sheet. It is set as such: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(generalFault.Address & ":" & dose.Address)

Comment: @ScottCraner I actually just change that line to only Range(generalFault.Address & ":" & dose.Address) and now it is working